# How to convert the dataframe to array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy, dataframe

I have read data from excel like the followings:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Location = r'C:\temp\test.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(Location, '4bar',     header=0,     parse_cols=0)

data
Out[80]: 
             10V        11V
0     -60.531006 -31.539307
1      -2.547607 -30.776367
2      58.487549  48.569336
3      72.220459  74.509277
4      64.591064  74.509277
5      54.672852  60.013428
```

I want to put the column '10V' and '11V' into two arrays. In order to process the data with filter coefficients.
But I don't know how to copy column to array or how to access/operate the element directly in DataFrame?

Can anyone give me a hint?
Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest going through pandas documentation, taking the first Pandas tutorials, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked question does not really answer how to access columns. (There may be other questions/answers that do so, though)

Comment: The mentioned question/solution couldn't help me really. But thank you all for the discussion. I am just beginning to learn python since this week. I will read the Pandas Tutorials as the next step.

Comment: df.to_numpy() -> this should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`as_matrix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) function.

```
import pandas as pd

Location = r'C:\temp\test.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(Location, '4bar', header=0, parse_cols=0)
numpy_data = data.as_matrix()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It is what I wanted!

Comment: It's done. It was my first question. Now I understand the process here;-)

Answer (score 0):

Column names can be used as indices such as `data['10V']`.

You should really check out the [Pandas tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#getting).